Quotienting Banach space by $\{T^nx \rightarrow 0\}$
Suppose $X$ is a reflexive Banach space and $T: X \rightarrow X$ is a bounded linear operator. Let $Z = Z_T = \overline{\{\lim_{n\to\infty}T^nx= 0\}}$.
If $X$ is finite dimensional then natural map on the quotient $\hat{T}: X/Z_T \rightarrow X/Z_T$ satisfies $Z_{\hat{T}} = 0$.
I don't think the same is true for infinite dimensional spaces, but do not see how to produce an example where this holds.
In terms of distances, a counterexample would have to have an $x \in X$ so that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(T^nx, Z_T) = 0$, but itself doesn't satisfy $|T^nx| \rightarrow 0$.

Are you able to provide more detail on what the quotient operator $\hat{T}$ is? This is not the standard definitions of a quotient operator between Banach spaces. It may also be helpful to sketch an argument of why the result is valid in the finite-dimensional case to see what goes wrong in the infinite-dimensional case.

I meant the map induced on the quotient. If finite dimensions, it is trivial of the Jordan theorem - $Z_T$ is the span of generalized eigenvectors of modulus smaller than one.  A counterexample would have spectrum intersecting the circle.

Maybe one should first check the case when $X$ is a Hilbert space. Then $Z_T$ has an orthogonal complement which is isomorphic to $X/Z_T$. That could help.
